# Webform submission edit - redirect after edit

Tags: webforms, redirection

I have a webform where I expect users to edit their submissions from time to time.  I want to redirect users upon submission of the submission edit to another node - say node/2 - (back to another node which lists their previous submissions in a view).  How can I acheive this redirect?

Note - this is not about redirecting after the initial submission of the webform.  It is about redirecting after editing an already existing submission.

Answer (score 0):

try using [rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules), it has a full featured of triggering actions with conditions like content type, user roles, ... etc.

Take a look at the [documentation](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/rules) if needed.